# EKS with EFS: what happens in case of instance crash?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, instance, amazon-eks

I have some micro applications deployed to EKS and they are using an EFS drive - to store critical data - through storage class and PVC. The question: what happens if the instance on which the pods are running crashes? Will the EFS be remounted in the newly upcoming pods? If that is not the case, how can it be ensured?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a launch template with the corresponding `user data` script in which you add the EFS mount instructions. So each time a new node is started then the `user data` will run right after booting.

Find more about the LT and the user data [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-eks-readme.html)

Comment: EKS has already created the launch templates and ASGs when I created the node groups. Your answer suggests that EFS remount needs to be done manually which sounds weird. How is an EKS production cluster prepared for node crash? Data on EFS sounds good but in case of a crashing node this should be mounted automatically on the new node + all the PVs and PVCs should work.